# I have recently started working wit ROS and im currently installing Noetic on my Ubuntu 20.04 and everything goes smoothly until i compile Turtlebot

Tags: python, cmake, ros, ubuntu-20.04, catkin

I compiled and installed everything from ros wiki and noetic got installed properly and i checked by running roscore command and also gazebo got installed rightly too. Then to work with turtlebot, I created a Catkin workspace and cloned the git repositories by following this tutorial : https://emanual.robotis.com/docs/en/platform/turtlebot3/simulation/

after running the `cd ~/catkin_ws && catkin_make` command i get the following error:

```
*Base path: /home/areebpc/catkin_ws
Source space: /home/areebpc/catkin_ws/src
Build space: /home/areebpc/catkin_ws/build
Devel space: /home/areebpc/catkin_ws/devel
Install space: /home/areebpc/catkin_ws/install
####
#### Running command: "cmake /home/areebpc/catkin_ws/src -DCATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX=/home/areebpc/catkin_ws/devel -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/home/areebpc/catkin_ws/install -G Unix Makefiles" in "/home/areebpc/catkin_ws/build"
####
-- Using CATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX: /home/areebpc/catkin_ws/devel
-- Using CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH: /home/areebpc/catkin_ws/devel;/opt/ros/noetic
-- This workspace overlays: /home/areebpc/catkin_ws/devel;/opt/ros/noetic
-- Found PythonInterp: /usr/bin/python3 (found suitable version "3.8.5", minimum required is "3") 
-- Using PYTHON_EXECUTABLE: /usr/bin/python3
-- Using Debian Python package layout
-- Using empy: /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/em.py
-- Using CATKIN_ENABLE_TESTING: ON
-- Call enable_testing()
-- Using CATKIN_TEST_RESULTS_DIR: /home/areebpc/catkin_ws/build/test_results
-- Forcing gtest/gmock from source, though one was otherwise available.
-- Found gtest sources under '/usr/src/googletest': gtests will be built
-- Found gmock sources under '/usr/src/googletest': gmock will be built
-- Found PythonInterp: /usr/bin/python3 (found version "3.8.5") 
-- Using Python nosetests: /usr/bin/nosetests3
-- catkin 0.8.9
-- BUILD_SHARED_LIBS is on
-- BUILD_SHARED_LIBS is on
/opt/ros/noetic/share/catkin/cmake/em/order_packages.cmake.em:23: error: <class 'RuntimeError'>: Multiple packages found with the same name "turtlebot3":
- share/turtlebot3
- turtlebot3/turtlebot3
Multiple packages found with the same name "turtlebot3_bringup":
- share/turtlebot3_bringup
- turtlebot3/turtlebot3_bringup
Multiple packages found with the same name "turtlebot3_description":
- share/turtlebot3_description
- turtlebot3/turtlebot3_description
Multiple packages found with the same name "turtlebot3_example":
- share/turtlebot3_example
- turtlebot3/turtlebot3_example
Multiple packages found with the same name "turtlebot3_msgs":
- share/turtlebot3_msgs
- turtlebot3_msgs
Multiple packages found with the same name "turtlebot3_navigation":
- share/turtlebot3_navigation
- turtlebot3/turtlebot3_navigation
Multiple packages found with the same name "turtlebot3_slam":
- share/turtlebot3_slam
- turtlebot3/turtlebot3_slam
Multiple packages found with the same name "turtlebot3_teleop":
- share/turtlebot3_teleop
- turtlebot3/turtlebot3_teleop
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/em.py", line 3302, in <module>
    if __name__ == '__main__': main()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/em.py", line 3300, in main
    invoke(sys.argv[1:])
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/em.py", line 3283, in invoke
    interpreter.wrap(interpreter.file, (file, name))
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/em.py", line 2295, in wrap
    self.fail(e)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/em.py", line 2284, in wrap
    callable(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/em.py", line 2359, in file
    self.safe(scanner, done, locals)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/em.py", line 2401, in safe
    self.parse(scanner, locals)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/em.py", line 2421, in parse
    token.run(self, locals)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/em.py", line 1425, in run
    interpreter.execute(self.code, locals)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/em.py", line 2595, in execute
    _exec(statements, self.globals, locals)
  File "<string>", line 17, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/catkin_pkg/topological_order.py", line 147, in topological_order
    for path, package in find_packages(space).items():
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/catkin_pkg/packages.py", line 96, in find_packages
    raise RuntimeError('\n'.join(duplicates))
RuntimeError: Multiple packages found with the same name "turtlebot3":
- share/turtlebot3
- turtlebot3/turtlebot3
Multiple packages found with the same name "turtlebot3_bringup":
- share/turtlebot3_bringup
- turtlebot3/turtlebot3_bringup
Multiple packages found with the same name "turtlebot3_description":
- share/turtlebot3_description
- turtlebot3/turtlebot3_description
Multiple packages found with the same name "turtlebot3_example":
- share/turtlebot3_example
- turtlebot3/turtlebot3_example
Multiple packages found with the same name "turtlebot3_msgs":
- share/turtlebot3_msgs
- turtlebot3_msgs
Multiple packages found with the same name "turtlebot3_navigation":
- share/turtlebot3_navigation
- turtlebot3/turtlebot3_navigation
Multiple packages found with the same name "turtlebot3_slam":
- share/turtlebot3_slam
- turtlebot3/turtlebot3_slam
Multiple packages found with the same name "turtlebot3_teleop":
- share/turtlebot3_teleop
- turtlebot3/turtlebot3_teleop
CMake Error at /opt/ros/noetic/share/catkin/cmake/safe_execute_process.cmake:11 (message):
  
  execute_process(/home/areebpc/catkin_ws/build/catkin_generated/env_cached.sh
  "/usr/bin/python3" "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/em.py" "--raw-errors"
  "-F" "/home/areebpc/catkin_ws/build/catkin_generated/order_packages.py"
  "-o" "/home/areebpc/catkin_ws/build/catkin_generated/order_packages.cmake"
  "/opt/ros/noetic/share/catkin/cmake/em/order_packages.cmake.em") returned
  error code 1
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /opt/ros/noetic/share/catkin/cmake/em_expand.cmake:25 (safe_execute_process)
  /opt/ros/noetic/share/catkin/cmake/catkin_workspace.cmake:35 (em_expand)
  CMakeLists.txt:69 (catkin_workspace)
-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/areebpc/catkin_ws/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/home/areebpc/catkin_ws/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
Invoking "cmake" failed*
```

i also checked the CMakeOutput.log and CMakeError.log but i could not see where the problem lies.

Answer (score 1):

While installing, are you sure you are installing via noetic?

1. `cd ~/catkin_ws/src/`
2. `git clone -b noetic-devel https://github.com/ROBOTIS-GIT/turtlebot3_simulations.git`
3. `cd ~/catkin_ws && catkin_make`

If you followed this step it should work. You could try deleting and reinstalling the turtlebot3 files. Make sure the setup is noetic.